# which version of spice will support on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am an engineering student and I need to use SPICE for my HomeWork

It is SPICE by CADENCE

I want to use its free version, is it possible?

PS
Ubuntu is the best exp this :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu(release, server/desktop) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they only support RHEL/Suse for Linux distributions. There are open source alternatives like [ngspice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/From_PSpice_to_ngspice-gEDA). As a CSE, I suggest you stick with the tools provided to you on the supported platforms. You can always run this stuff in a VM. The curriculum is grueling enough without tools that don't work when you need them the most.

MATLAB runs native on Ubuntu, (which you're going to become *very familiar* with) though I wouldn't recommend that either because not all the toolboxes you might need are available for it (iirc) and the simulink gui is buggy.